# pull items from one array and add to an existing array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have existing array and would like to add another object array to each item where the IDs match.

```
var existingData = [
    {
        "id": "0100",
        "name": "name 1",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 1",
            "Lorem blah blah 1.1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0200",
        "name": "name 2",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 2",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0300",
        "name": "name 3",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.2",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.4"
        ]
    }
];
```

and the following array is my second array in which the "relatedId" will be the same as the IDs in the existingArray:

```
var data2 = [
  {"CandidateName": "Mary", "relatedId": ["0100", "0200"]},
  { "CandidateName": "John", "relatedId": ["0200"]},
  { "CandidateName":"Peter", "relatedId": ["0300", "0100"]},
  { "CandidateName": "Paul", "relatedId": ["0300"]}
];
```

If IDs match, I want to pull the "CandidateName" from data2 and put it into the existingData.

This particular question is has been extended from here => [Group Javascript array of objects by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634912/group-javascript-array-of-objects-by-id)

I have already made an attempt but I am not getting very far as the browser hangs:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(r, el) {

  // THIS INNER LOOP MAKES THE BROWSER HANG!!!
  data2.forEach(function (a){
    console.log('a',a); 
  });

  var e = el.id.slice(0, 2);
  if (!o[e]) {
    o[e] = {
      id: el.id,
      name: el.name,
      message: []
    }
    r.push(o[e]);
  }
  o[e].message.push(el.message);
  return r;
}, [])
```

So I want to end up with something like this:

```
var existingData = [
    {
        "id": "0100",
        "name": "name 1",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 1",
            "Lorem blah blah 1.1"
        ],
        "CandidateName": ["Mary", "Peter"]
    },
    {
        "id": "0200",
        "name": "name 2",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 2",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.2"
        ],
        "CandidateName": ["Mary", "John"]
    },
    {
        "id": "0300",
        "name": "name 3",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.2",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.4"
        ],
        "CandidateName": ["Peter", "Paul"]
    }
]
```

Comment: It appears that your situation might be simplified by having `existingData` be an Object that contains Objects instead of an array of Objects. The keys for `existingData` could then be the `id` of each Object.  This would allow you to have direct access instead of having to go searching through the array each time you want the object that corresponds to the `id`.  This is, more or less, the exact type of situation for which Objects exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another ES6 solution:

```
data2.forEach( function (obj) {
    obj.relatedId.forEach( id => this.get(id).candidateName.push(obj.CandidateName));
}, new Map(existingData.map (
    obj => [obj.id, Object.assign(obj, { 'candidateName': [] } )] 
)));
```

```js
var existingData = [
    {
        "id": "0100",
        "name": "name 1",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 1",
            "Lorem blah blah 1.1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0200",
        "name": "name 2",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 2",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0300",
        "name": "name 3",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.2",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.4"
        ]
    }
];

var data2 = [
  {"CandidateName": "Mary", "relatedId": ["0100", "0200"]},
  { "CandidateName": "John", "relatedId": ["0200"]},
  { "CandidateName":"Peter", "relatedId": ["0300", "0100"]},
  { "CandidateName": "Paul", "relatedId": ["0300"]}
];

data2.forEach( function (obj) {
    obj.relatedId.forEach( id => this.get(id).candidateName.push(obj.CandidateName));
}, new Map(existingData.map (
    obj => [obj.id, Object.assign(obj, { 'candidateName': [] } )] 
)));

console.log(existingData);
```

This turns the *existingData* into a map, keyed by *id*, while adding the *candidateName* array (empty) to the objects.

This map is passed as the second argument to `forEach`, thus defining it as the `this` object.

Inside the `forEach` on *data2* elements, the *relatedId* values are iterated and for each of these *id* values the corresponding *existingData* object's *candidateName* array is extended with the *CandidateName*.

Comment: Shortest lines of code and ultra fast. Must try to implment this. ES6 is something I've recently started looking at so must use this one. Thanks trincot

Answer (score 3):

It's far more efficient to create a hash map from `data2` so you only ever iterate that array once. The keys would be the id's

Then while you iterate `existingData` it is a simple  merge

```
var candidatesById = data2.reduce(function(a, c){
   c.relatedId.forEach(function(id){
       a[id] = a[id] || [];
       a[id].push(c.CandidateName);           
   });
   return a;
},{});

existingData.forEach(function(item){
    item.CandidateName = candidatesById[item.id] || [];// empty array if no match
})
```

Comment: Well done, this too worked. Thanks also. It isolated just the candidate names which is also useful. Many thanks.

Comment: note the difference in how many times you are iterating the `data2` array vs just doing it once. On big data sets this is very significant

Comment: Yes, which would explain why it was hanging I suppose?

Answer (score 2):

Try this! The concept being, use the initial data, loop through and search for IDs, add applicable data.

Do note that this isn't a particularly efficient solution.

```js
var existingData = [{
  "id": "0100",
  "name": "name 1",
  "message": [
    "Lorem blah blah 1",
    "Lorem blah blah 1.1"
  ]
}, {
  "id": "0200",
  "name": "name 2",
  "message": [
    "Lorem blah blah 2",
    "Lorem blah blah 2.1",
    "Lorem blah blah 2.2"
  ]
}, {
  "id": "0300",
  "name": "name 3",
  "message": [
    "Lorem blah blah 3",
    "Lorem blah blah 3.1",
    "Lorem blah blah 3.2",
    "Lorem blah blah 3.3",
    "Lorem blah blah 3.4"
  ]
}];

var toCombine = [{
  "CandidateName": "Mary",
  "relatedId": ["0100", "0200"]
}, {
  "CandidateName": "John",
  "relatedId": ["0200"]
}, {
  "CandidateName": "Peter",
  "relatedId": ["0300", "0100"]
}, {
  "CandidateName": "Paul",
  "relatedId": ["0300"]
}];

function merge() {
  existingData.forEach(function(initialItem) {
    toCombine.forEach(function(referenceItem) {
      if (referenceItem.relatedId.indexOf(initialItem.id) >= 0) {
        if (!Array.isArray(initialItem.CandidateName)) {
          initialItem.CandidateName = [];
        }
        initialItem.CandidateName.push(referenceItem.CandidateName);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(existingData);
}

merge();
```

Comment: Score! It works. Well done. I'm going to have to take a leaf out of your book(s). Literally

Comment: It appears as though it would be more efficient to iterate through the related data array rather than the existing data based on the example given. There is no guarantee that there will be a related record for every existing record which will result in unnecessary iterations. Since you definitely have to search through the existing array for each related item to check their IDs, you may as well only loop through them once. Your code looks good otherwise. I would personally switch to an object instead of array as mentioned above if possible.

Comment: I know I went about it the wrong way to start with.

Answer (score 1):

May be we can do something like this in ES6 too; Well.. i create a hash table from `data2` and use it as a `this` object in `map`.

```js
var existingData = [
    {
        "id": "0100",
        "name": "name 1",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 1",
            "Lorem blah blah 1.1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0200",
        "name": "name 2",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 2",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 2.2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0300",
        "name": "name 3",
        "message": [
            "Lorem blah blah 3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.1",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.2",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.3",
            "Lorem blah blah 3.4"
        ]
    }
],
 data2 = [
  {"CandidateName": "Mary", "relatedId": ["0100", "0200"]},
  { "CandidateName": "John", "relatedId": ["0200"]},
  { "CandidateName":"Peter", "relatedId": ["0300", "0100"]},
  { "CandidateName": "Paul", "relatedId": ["0300"]}
],

newExistingData = existingData.map(function(o){
                                     o.CandidateName = this[o.id];
                                     return o;
                                   }, data2.reduce((h,o) => (o.relatedId.reduce((p,c) => (p[c] ? p[c].push(o.CandidateName)
                                                                                        : p[c] = [o.CandidateName],p),h),h),{}));
console.log(newExistingData);
```

Comment: Quite keen on ES^ implementation of this but I'm getting a 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined" around the 
`=> (o.relatedId.reduce(` block of code on the third line of your code. Any ideas of how to check for 'undefined' type?

Comment: @Mr. Benedict Wow.. I checked it with FF v50 and Chrome v54.. and running fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm actually using Chrome but I think the issue is with the real data set which is more extensive. There will be instances where there will be no `relatedId`s so when you 'reduce', I guess it will not know what to do next so it come up as undefined. How do you overcome such scenarios?

Comment: @Mr. Benedict Now i see.. This code expects the `relatedId` to be at least `[]` In case there is no such property then there is always `data2.reduce((h,o) => o.relatedId ? (o.relatedId.reduce((p,c) => ... : h` option.