# Compare IDs in a two-dimensional array with IDs in another two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, another in the series of grouping Javascript arrays of objects by ID but this time, we have an array of IDs in an object of arrays (item3) which will be compared with another array of objects.

```
var existingArray = [
    {
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0200","0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0100","0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0100"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0200", "0100"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    }
]
```

Here's our favourite DATA2 array which contains the piece of information we want to pull out (CandidateName) if the "relatedId" is the same as the any of the IDs in item3 in EXISTINGARRAY.

```
var data2 = [
    {"CandidateName": "Mary", "relatedId": ["0100", "0200"]},
    { "CandidateName": "John", "relatedId": ["0200"]},
    { "CandidateName":"Peter", "relatedId": ["0300", "0100"]},
    { "CandidateName": "Paul", "relatedId": ["0300"]}
];
```

So the idea is if any of the IDs in data2[i].relatedId[j] === existingArray[k].item3[l], pull out the "CandidateName" and add it to the EXISTINGARRAY so we end up with something like the following.

```
existingArray = [
    {
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0200","0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5",
      "item6": ["Mary", "Jonh", "Peter", "Paul"]
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0100","0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5",
      "item6": ["Mary", "Peter", "Paul"]
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0100"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5",
      "item6": ["Mary", "Peter"]
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5",
      "item6": ["Peter", "Paul"]
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0200", "0100"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5",
      "item6": ["Mary", "John","Peter"]
    }
]
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Why doesn't first one gets attached with `"item6": ["Mary", "John",  "Peter", "Paul"]`

Comment: How does this differ in essence from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709805/pull-items-from-one-array-and-add-to-an-existing-array-javascript)? And are you still planning to accept an answer there?

Comment: I have tried existingArray.reduce and within that, I did another data2.reduce but no joy.

You're right @trincot, the intended outcome is essentially the same but the fact that I am looping through both arrays and within both, I am looping through two more arrays. Just got pretty messy really quickly.

Comment: @Ridcully I want to pull CandidateName from data2 and put them into existingArray if the IDs in item3 inside existingArray matches relatedId within data2. See where it says: "so we end up with something like the following."

Comment: I agree with Ridcully; John should be in item6 of the first object, since 200 is a link between John and item3 of that object.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just noticed that that "John" should be in the first set as well. I've added the name "John" to the first "item6". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ES6 solution for this:

```
existingArray.forEach( function (obj) {
    obj.item6 = [...new Set(obj.item3.reduce( (acc, id) => acc.concat(this.get(id)), [] ))]
}, data2.reduce (
    (acc, obj) => obj.relatedId.reduce (
        (acc, id) => acc.set(id, (acc.get(id) || []).concat(obj.CandidateName)), acc
    ), new Map()
));
```

```js
var existingArray = [
    {
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0200","0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0100","0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0100"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0300"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    },{
      "item1": "Blah1",
      "item2": "blah2",
      "item3": ["0200", "0100"],
      "item4": "blah4",
      "item5": "blah5"
    }
]

var data2 = [
    {"CandidateName": "Mary", "relatedId": ["0100", "0200"]},
    { "CandidateName": "John", "relatedId": ["0200"]},
    { "CandidateName":"Peter", "relatedId": ["0300", "0100"]},
    { "CandidateName": "Paul", "relatedId": ["0300"]}
];

existingArray.forEach( function (obj) {
    obj.item6 = [...new Set(obj.item3.reduce( (acc, id) => acc.concat(this.get(id)), [] ))]
}, data2.reduce (
    (acc, obj) => obj.relatedId.reduce (
        (acc, id) => acc.set(id, (acc.get(id) || []).concat(obj.CandidateName)), acc
    ), new Map()
));

console.log(existingArray);
```

#### Explanation

The code really starts at the end, with the creation of an empty `Map`:

```
new Map()
```

This becomes the variable (named `acc`) that accumulates data while `data2` is iterated with `reduce`:

```
data2.reduce
```

This `reduce` operation is nested in order to iterate each `relatedId` individually. If the accumulated value (`acc`) does not yet contain the found id, a new array is created:

```
acc.get(id) || []
```

... otherwise the found array value is used. To that the candidate name is appended:

```
.concat(obj.CandidateName)
```

... and this is put back into `acc` for key `id`:

```
acc.set(id, ...)
```

As the `set` method returns `acc` itself, it works very nicely with `reduce` which needs this return value in order to pass `acc` again to the next call of the callback.

The result of the outer `reduce` call is this a `Map` that is keyed by all `id` values found in `data2`, and the value for each is an array of associated names.

This value is then passed as second argument to the `forEach` call, and thus becomes the value of `this`. So when you see:

```
this.get(id)
```

it is retrieving the candidate name array for `id` from the `Map` described above.

In the `forEach` callback another `reduce` is made to iterate over the `id` values in `item3`:

```
obj.item3.reduce
```

This accumulates to an array of names which is then passed to the `Set` constructor:

```
new Set(...)
```

This is done to remove duplicates from the array of names. This `Set` is immediately converted to an array again with the spread operator:

```
[...new Set()]
```

And so all `item6` properties get their value.

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down Trincot. I just realised what you meant by "accepted answer" on the previous  version question. I thought I had clicked the tick but I didn't. Works like a charm :)

Comment: Professor @trincot, I'm still getting to grips with ES6, how to do check for "TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined". Normally, I would do an if statement and check if something exists or check for length greater than zero or something. How do I do this with your very elegant ES6 code please?

Comment: When you get that error on the second `reduce` (the inner one), it means `data2` has an entry without `relatedId` (or it exists, but has value  `undefined`). If you cannot fix  `data2`, then in my solution replace `obj.relatedId.reduce` by `(obj.relatedId || []).reduce`. If the error is on the first `reduce`, then your `data2` variable is undefined, which would mean you didn't use the correct variable name.

Comment: Thanks for responding @trincot, I'll give that a try. I think the variables are correct. I'll try this instead
`(obj.relatedId || []).reduce`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop existingArray and add item6 with `map()`, and to create that array you can first use `filter()` and `some()` to filter objects that contain same values in relatedId as current object in existingArray and then just use `map()` to return only names and return object.

```js
var existingArray = [{"item1":"Blah1","item2":"blah2","item3":["0200","0300"],"item4":"blah4","item5":"blah5"},{"item1":"Blah1","item2":"blah2","item3":["0100","0300"],"item4":"blah4","item5":"blah5"},{"item1":"Blah1","item2":"blah2","item3":["0100"],"item4":"blah4","item5":"blah5"},{"item1":"Blah1","item2":"blah2","item3":["0300"],"item4":"blah4","item5":"blah5"},{"item1":"Blah1","item2":"blah2","item3":["0200","0100"],"item4":"blah4","item5":"blah5"}];
var data2 = [{"CandidateName":"Mary","relatedId":["0100","0200"]},{"CandidateName":"John","relatedId":["0200"]},{"CandidateName":"Peter","relatedId":["0300","0100"]},{"CandidateName":"Paul","relatedId":["0300"]}];

var result = existingArray.map(function(o) {
  o.item6 = data2.filter(function(e) {
    return o.item3.some(function(a) {
      return e.relatedId.indexOf(a) != -1;
    })
  }).map(function(e) {
    return e.CandidateName;
  })
  return o;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the provision of this answer. I have actually used this answer as opposed to the elegant ES6 answer as I am able to handle if property is undefined. Between your code and @trincot 's code, I have managed to finally solve it. Many thanks.